# for loop which detects consecutive values

Tags: c++, math

I am new in c++ and have a little task. At texas holdem poker you try to get combinations with 7 cards. One of the possible combinations is a straight where under the 7 cards at least 5 consecutive cards are. Numbers two to ten are are numbercards, 11 jack, 12 queen, 13 king and 14 As. Two cards are consectuve when the difference is 1.

The function `recognizestreet (int cards[7])` should become created which get commited with 7 increasing values.The function should check wether under the 7 cards is a straight. If a straight gets found the function should give back the values of the highest card and if no straight is founded the value 0.

**Thats what I have until now:**

```
recognizestreet (int cards[7]) {
    int cards[13]={2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14};
    boolean street = false;
        for(int i = 0; i <= 7; i++){

    if (cards[i+] - cards[i] = 1 ) {
//do something


}
if (street = true) {
}
if (street = false) {
}
}
```

Comment: You probably meant to write `if (cards[i+] - cards[i] == 1 )`. Same for `if (street = true) {` et. al.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think what you want is something along the lines of...

```
int recognizestreet (int cards[7]) {

    bool street = true;
    for(int i = 0; street && i < 6; i++){    
        if (cards[i+1] - cards[i] != 1 ) {
            street = false;
        }
    }

    if (street) {
      return cards[6];
    }
    else {
      return 0;
    }
}
```